# How can i find if the date lies between two dates

Tags: python, django

I have the date like

```
date['min'] = '2013-11-11'
date['max'] = '2013-11-23'
```

Is there any single line function which can return true if date lies in that range.

I mean if only `date.min` is provided then i need to check if given date is grater than it and if only max is provided then i need to check if its less than that. and if both are provided then whether it falls between them

Comment: Does it have to be single line? :)

Comment: well it can be two lines but i don't want to have if else multiple times

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dates in the form `YYYY-MM-DD` can be compared alphabetically as well:

```
'2013-11-11' < '2013-11-15' < '2013-11-23'

date['min'] < your_date < date['max']
```

This won't work correctly for other formats, such as `DD.MM.YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`. In that case you have to parse the strings and convert them into `datetime` objects.

If don't know whether the min/max variables are present, you can do:

```
date.get('min', '0000-00-00') < your_date < date.get('max', '9999-99-99')
```

and replace the default text values with anything you prefer.

Comment: what about if i don't have two values. i mean i don't want to use if else. is there any shortcut. my all dates are in yyyy-mm-dd format only

Comment: @user2294401 - ok, see my updated answer, which works even if min/max or any of them is not present.

Answer (score 2):

I think simple comparison works for that.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta, date
>>> min_date = date.today()
>>> max_date = date.today() + timedelta(days=7)
>>> d1 = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
>>> d2 = date.today() + timedelta(days=10)
>>> min_date < d1 < max_date
True
>>> min_date < d2 < max_date
False
```

Here is the updated version:

```
def is_in_range(d, min=date.min, max=date.max):
    if max:
        return min < d < max
    return min < d


print is_in_range(d1, min_date, max_date)
print is_in_range(d2, min_date, max_date)
print is_in_range(d1, min_date)
print is_in_range(d2, min_date)

True
False
True
True
```

Comment: i want the system to return true even if max_date is empty

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with date objects:

```
from datetime import date
in_range = (first_date or date.min) < my_date < (second_date or date.max)
```

Comment: how it will work if i have second_date which is less that my_date. won't it return true